# Getting the latest order placed by a particular customer from file

Tags: c

Basically, I am trying to develop a customer order system. I wrote a method where the system gets the latest order placed by a particular customer. The user is asked to enter the customer id number in order to get the corresponding order. This function is not working properly because it is getting the first order placed and not the LAST one. I used fseek in my method but it is still not working.

```
void ViewLatestOrder()
{
    order o;
    char Customerid[10];


    ofp=fopen("orders.dat","rb");

    printf("\nEnter the Customer ID: \n");
    scanf("%s",&Customerid);

    rewind(ofp);
    fseek(ofp, -sizeof(order), SEEK_END);

    while(fread(&o,sizeof(o),1,ofp)==1 && !feof(ofp))
    {
        if(strcmp(Customerid,o.CustomerID)== 0)
        {

            printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
            printf("\t\t Order Details of %s\n\n",o.CustomerID);
            printf("========================================================\n\n");

            printf("Product Name: %s\n",o.ProductName);
            printf("Product Quantities: %d\n",o.ProductQuantities);
            printf("Total Order Price: %.2f\n",o.TotalOrderPrice);


            printf("========================================================\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            fseek(ofp, -2*sizeof(order), SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }


    OrdersSubMenu();
    fclose(ofp);

    }
```

Comment: OT: Since you're purposely seeking to one-order *before* eof, are you expecting feof() to be variant in your while expression?

Comment: Try to print the current position with `printf("position: %d\n", ftell(ofp));`. This should help you to get rid of the problem. Put a `break;` after you find the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right, you're just failing to break out of the while loop on the first successfull find. It then continues to find and print all previous orders as well.

```
if(strcmp(Customerid,o.CustomerID)== 0)
{
  ... // printing
  break; 
}
```

Comment: I think the code is not right, as I said on my answer, but what you tell him he must do is completely right. Do you mind if I add it to my answer?

Comment: I was asking acraig, who is the author of this answer, sorry. Anyway, check his answer, it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using **feof()** and **fseek()** upon the same **FILE*** seems not right, as stated by the documentation:

> [...] A successful call to the  fseek()  function  clears  the
>          end-of-file  indicator  for  the  stream  and undoes any effects of the
>          ungetc(3) function on the same stream. [...]

Second to this you should check if you just rode the first entry in the file by something like:

```
[...]
else
        {
            if(fseek(ofp, -2*sizeof(order), SEEK_CUR) == sizeof(order))
                break; // End the while if we rode ALL the records
        }
[...]
```

Anyway I'm really failing to discover why in the world this, as you did say, prints the first and not the last entry...

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1:**

```
scanf("%s",&Customerid);
```

In above statement, `%s` is expecting `char *` but you are passing it the address of `char *` means `char **`, so your statement should be..

```
scanf("%s", Customerid);
```

**Point 2:**

use `feof` before `fread`, after `fread`, `feof` will return `1` it your case, So statement should be..

```
while(!feof(ofp) && fread(&o,sizeof(o),1,ofp)==1)
```

**Point 3:**

Use `Break;` inside `if` block as @acraig5075 mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s",&Customerid);
```

If `CustomerId` is `int` `%s` expects `char *`